# Sample C code to compensate for TCP stream sockets?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, client-server, tcpclient

I am a beginner in socket programming. I am looking for example c code to compensate for the fact that tcp is stream based i.e one send in client may not equal on recv in server.

How do I make sure that when i send a message from client like this :

```
strcpy(send_data, "Hello Server");
send(sock,send_data,strlen(send_data), 0);
```

it gets received on the server side exactly ..

I know that tcp is stream based so that message may get fragmented and it may require multiple recv calls on server to get the whole message.

**But how do i make the server keep on receiving until full message is received?**

I know the theory behind it  ..  **I am looking for examples in C** ( preferably full codes for both client and server side )

Comment: "preferably full codes for both client and server side". Check out the Stevens Unix Network Programming book.

Comment: You might find the old but good [Beej's guide](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html) to socket programming useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you create a protocol.  If it's always a c-style string you can just look for a NUL terminator.

Then you read and put the data into a buffer as you receive it.  Then you parse the buffer looking for your terminator, process the data (whatever that means to your application), and remove it from the buffer.

That's also how you send, as you never know how much data will be sent on each call to send.  Put what you want to send into a local memory buffer, call to send, and remove however many bytes were actually sent from the local buffer.

Also, Stack Overflow isn't a site to ask people to point you at example code - that's Google.  It's a place to post YOUR code and have people help you find out what's wrong with it.